# how can YQL output a XML in my python script?

Tags: xml, yql

I know the console can output a XML or a JSON format output by using YQL.

But When I want to save the output file, I do it in my python script by using follow codes:

```
import yql
query = 'blablabla'
y = yql.Public()
result = y.execute(query)
```

and the result is a dict but I want to save it in a file with the XML format. How can I make it?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's on the [TODO list](https://github.com/project-fondue/python-yql/blob/master/TODO).

You can fork the code. The result format is defined in the following class:

- [YQLObject](https://github.com/project-fondue/python-yql/blob/master/yql/__init__.py#L276)

And referenced as a return value:

- [execute method](https://github.com/project-fondue/python-yql/blob/master/yql/__init__.py#L297)